# Update Function not working

Tags: mysql, sql, servlets

I'm trying to to do an update and it's not working and throwing this error:

> sql=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@2b4a207c: update backup.add_event set title='hhh',eventDesc='jj',StartTime='02:00:AM' EndTime='02:00:AM',Budget=234.0,StartDate='2017-09-01',EndDate='2017-09-01',Environment=null
>   Error=Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EndTime='02:00:AM',Budget=234.0,StartDate='2017-09-01',EndDate='2017-09-01',Envi' at line 1

I tried checking like a hundred times and seriously can't find the error

```
DBAO.java:
....

public boolean updateEvent(AddEvents myEvent)throws Exception{
    try
    {
        String updateStatement= "update backup.add_event set title=?,eventDesc=?,StartTime=? EndTime=?,Budget=?";
        updateStatement = updateStatement+",StartDate=?,EndDate=?,Environment=?";
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
        prepStmt.setString(1,myEvent.getTitle());
        prepStmt.setString(2,myEvent.getEventDesc());
        prepStmt.setString(3,myEvent.getStartTime());
        prepStmt.setString(4,myEvent.getEndTime());
        prepStmt.setDouble(5,myEvent.getBudget());
        prepStmt.setDate(6,(Date) myEvent.getStartDate());
        prepStmt.setDate(7,(Date) myEvent.getEndDate());
        prepStmt.setString(8,myEvent.getEnvironment());


        System.out.println("sql=" +prepStmt.toString());
        int status = prepStmt.executeUpdate();
    if(status!=0)
    {
        System.out.println("Record updated");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Error:" +ex.getMessage());
}

}
}   
 UpdateServlet:
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import database.DBAO;
import model.AddEvents;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class UpdateServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/UpdateServlet")
public class UpdateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public UpdateServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //doGet(request, response);
        AddEvents myEvent = new AddEvents();

        myEvent.setTitle(request.getParameter("Title"));
        myEvent.setEventDesc(request.getParameter("EventDesc"));
        myEvent.setStartDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("StartDate")));
        myEvent.setEndDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("EndDate")));
        myEvent.setStartTime(request.getParameter("StartTime"));
        myEvent.setEndTime(request.getParameter("EndTime"));
        //myEvent.setBudget(request.getParameter("Budget"));
        myEvent.setBudget(Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("Budget")));
        myEvent.setEnvironment(request.getParameter(request.getParameter("Environment")));
        try
        {
            DBAO myDatabase = new DBAO();
            boolean status= myDatabase.updateEvent(myEvent);
            if(status)
            {
                HttpSession mysess = request.getSession(true);
                mysess.setAttribute("Event_Info", myEvent);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Retrieve.jsp").forward(request, response);

            }
            else{
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Update.jsp").forward(request,response);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error="+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *Please* trim your code down and only give us the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma between "StartTime=? EndTime=?".